# Filtering data from RDD using value sequence spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I need the help on the below use case:

**Question 1:** My RDD is of below format.Now from this RDD ,I want to exclude the rows where airport.code in("PUN","HAR","KAS")

```
    case class airport(code:String,city:String,airportname:String)
    val airportRdd=sparkSession.sparkContext.textFile("src/main/resources/airport_data.csv").
          map(x=>x.split(","))
    val airPortRddTransformed=airportRdd.map(x=>airport(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
    val trasnformedRdd=airPortRddTransformed.filter(air=>!(air.code.contains(seqValues:_*)))
```

But ! is not working .It is telling can not resolve symbol !.Can some one please help me.How to do negate in RDD.I have to use RDD approach only.

Also another question:

**Question 2 :** The data file is having 70 columns.I have a columns sequence:

```
val seqColumns=List("lat","longi","height","country")
```

I want to exclude these columns while loading the RDD.How can I do it.My production RDD is having 70 columns, I just really know the columns names to exclude.Not the index of every column.Again looking for it in RDD approach.I am aware on how to do it in Dataframe approach.

Comment: Would be better if you ask each question separately. Also try to provide some examples of the content or schema of  airport_data.csv

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1

Use `broadcast` to pass list of values to `filter` function. It seems _* in filter is not working. I changed condition to `!seqValues.value.contains(air.code)`

**Data sample: airport_data.csv**

```
C001,Pune,Pune Airport
C002,Mumbai,Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj International Airport
C003,New York,New York Airport
C004,Delhi,Delhi Airport
```

**Code snippet**

```
case class airport(code:String,city:String,airportname:String)
val seqValues=spark.sparkContext.broadcast(List("C001","C003"))
val airportRdd = spark.sparkContext.textFile("D:\\DataAnalysis\\airport_data.csv").map(x=>x.split(","))
val airPortRddTransformed = airportRdd.map(x=>airport(x(0),x(1),x(2)))
//airPortRddTransformed.foreach(println)
val trasnformedRdd = airPortRddTransformed.filter(air => !seqValues.value.contains(air.code))
trasnformedRdd.foreach(println)
```

**Output ->**

```
airport(C002,Mumbai,Chhatrapati Shivaji Maharaj International Airport)
airport(C004,Delhi,Delhi Airport)
```

Comment: gr8..Thank you so much..Let me just Try it out

Answer (score 0):

Things I would change:

1- You are reading a `.csv` as a TextFile and then spliting the lines based on `,`. You can save this step by reading the file like:

```
val df = spark.read.csv("src/main/resources/airport_data.csv")
```

2- Change the order of `contains`

```
val trasnformedRdd = airPortRddTransformed.filter(air => !(seqValues.contains(air.code)))
```